# How to enable or disable buttons in bulk?

Tags: android

I have 30 buttons in a page for each time slot like 9AM, 10AM ... for 3 days. I have to enable or disable the button based on the availability. Is there any easier way to enable or disable buttons at a time or i just have to follow the same method of using the button.setVisibility(view.GONE) for each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After initializing your 30 buttons, u can collect them in a `List<Button>`. For changing their visibility in bulk, u can just iterate through your list in a for loop and change their visibility. Something like below:

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

buttons.add(button1);
buttons.add(button2);
........


private void setButtonsVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
    if (buttons != null) {
        for (Button button : buttons) {
            button.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods

1. If the buttons have same parent layout you can set the visibility to `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` of the parent layout and it will be reflected to the button too.
2. If not than you have to set the visibility of each button or set the enabled property to true or false according to the condition.

Hope this works.